# Why do we take dx instead of dl here?

Tags: waves

In the derivation of power transmitted along a string in a travelling wave we write $dU=\frac{1}{2}{\omega}^2y^2dm=\frac{1}{2}{\omega}^2y^2{\mu}dx$

Shouldn't dm be written as ${\mu}dl$ insted of ${\mu}dx$(where $dl={\sqrt{(dx)^2+(dy)^2}}$)?

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: Sorry,. I edited it

Comment: Provided $A \ll \lambda,$ in which $A$ is amplitude, $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} \ll 1$, so it's fine to use $dx$ instead of $d \ell$ in this context.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. I wonder why this approximation was not mentioned anywhere.

Comment: Now I think about it, I'm not sure that the answer to your question rests on this approximation! If $\mu$ is the mass per unit length of the straight string, then even if the string is distorted (and lengthened) by the wave, $\mu dx$ is still the mass of length $d \ell$, since this will still have the mass of its original length, $dx$ !

Comment: @PhilipWood actually, it's still fine if $\partial y/\partial x$ is *not* small, so long as you formulate the physics by considering what happens to a small *undeformed* element of the string. The mass of that element doesn't change as it moves and deforms when its tension changes. I suspect the OP is getting in a muddle between an Eulerian and a Lagrangian model of the system - possibly without knowing that Euler and Lagrange invented two different ways to describe the physics, both of which are correct, but not if you use part of one and part of the other!

Comment: "actually, it's still fine if ∂/∂ is not small, so long as you formulate the physics by considering what happens to a small undeformed element of the string." That's what I meant in my last comment!

Comment: So as the string is deformed $\mu$ does not remain constant right?